# xcodebuild is stuck indefinitely when few tests are failed

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcuitest

I am using XCTest to run UI tests on iPhone.

Whenever few tests are failed, the `xcodebuild` command is stuck indefinitely without yielding any results. I have to terminate the build manually. I have observed the same behavior when the tests are executed from XCode(15.3).

Below are the settings from my test plan -
[image]

Can someone please help me how can I debug this behavior?

Comment: Nothing looks awry in your setup. Would have to look at this live to be of much help. I'd love to point you to a place where that could happen, but probably against TOS here.